# What does ni mean here?

Tags: particle-に

こさめ  漫画家に知り合いなんているか？
''Are there any acquaintances in mangaka?''

Can't find any other examples where someone asked the same so trying to figure out what it means, ''in mangaka'' doesn't sound natural

Answer (score 3):

"Among" is probably an easy way to parse the に here.  Logically / syntactically, it's basically the same as "in", but for a group, "among" works better as English.

> こさめ  漫画家**に**知り合いなんているか？
> "Are there (do you have) any acquaintances **among** manga authors?"

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Will remember this again if I see a similar sentence

Comment: @FirstNameLastName Welcome to the StackExchange. You don't have to comment thanking for an answer in the SE. If this answer solved your question, please accept it and upvote it.